# What is the current state of axion research theoretically?

Tags: group-theory, dark-matter, axion

Is the problem (the strong CP problem) that is solved by axions still considered a really big problem, like the missing mass terms that could be solved by the Higgs mechanism? Or is it more a "problem" like the hierachy problem?

Are axions (the additional PQ-Symmetry) considered as an awesome solution to this problem or is it a rather artificial one? (As a beginner this new ad-hoc symmetry seems very artificial to me)

PS: *Of course, I know there are review papers, but those are written by people working in the field. I'm hoping for something more unbiased.*

Comment: Uh, who except people in the field would know about it?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Uhm, everyone who spent some time studying QCD could answer the question whether the strong CP problem is a big thing or not? Almost every HEP physicist has an opinion when it comes to SUSY, but this doesn't mean that everyone works on SUSY theories....

Answer (score 2):

**I think the strong CP problem is still a pretty important problem.** Although some people don't worry too much about these fine-tuning problems. Just like some people didn't consider the [flatness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatness_problem%22Flattness%20problem%22) a big deal before the inflation theory explained it. So like every problem, it's as big as you make it. It depends on how much you value naturalness...

However, the discovery of an axion would be a major discovery (like a Higgs-boson big discovery). It's true that the PQ-theory might seem artificial at first ("This doesn't work? Just add an extra particle, that will do the job!"), but I think it's less artificial than having to make a value randomly small. Furthermore, axions could be part of CDM and they're easily implementable in e.g. string theory. So really, they seem fairly elegant to me.

Comment: Although I agree with the rest that you write, saying that the inflation theory explained the flatness problem is a bit subjective: Inflation is not known to be right or wrong yet, and yes, many people still don't consider flatness to belong to a list of problems. (Not to mention that the theory of inflation just irons everything out which might not have big aesthetic appeal to others.)